# sfdx package version create error: CustomizableCampaignInfluence report type is not available

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package, campaign-influence

I'm trying to create an unlocked package version with sfdx. The package has components that require custom campaign influence to be enabled in the org, and I have the appropriate setting in my definition file (scratch org config file): "campaignSettings": {"enableCampaignInfluence2": true}.

I was able to create previous package versions successfully, but now I'm getting this error on package version create, and the only thing I changed was adding reports and dashboards based on the CustomizableCampaignInfluence report type, which is a standard report type that gets generated when the custom campaign influence is enabled.

> ERROR running force:package:version:create:
> MultiTouchCampaignAttribution/Campaigns_Responses_Timeline_32e:
> ReportType: CustomizableCampaignInfluence is not
> available,MultiTouchCampaignAttribution/Revenue_by_Opportunity_Type_nhZ:
> ReportType: CustomizableCampaignInfluence is not
> available,MultiTouchAttributionDashboards/caDFoKVGnLTwriPidsJZVCMKlDyojs:
> In field: report - no Report named
> MultiTouchCampaignAttributionReports/Campaigns_Responses_Timeline_32e
> found,MultiTouchCampaignAttribution/Top_Campaigns_SB1: ReportType:
> CustomizableCampaignInfluence is not available"

I don't think I can add this report type because it's standard. Is there another setting I need to add to the definition file?

Comment: Are you passing the definition file to the version create command?

Comment: Yes, I tried including different parameters, and I've been including "--definitionfile config/project-scratch-def.json". It seems like it's still not pointing to it for some reason.